# Position: Sticky; not working for an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an image to be sticky and it isn't working. Here is my HTML and CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="media">
  <img class="sticky" src="mediabuttons.PNG" width="25%" height="25%">
</div>
```

**CSS** *for the div.*

```
.media{
   float: left;
   text-align: right;
   width: 15%;
   margin-top: 65px;
}
```

**CSS** *for the image.*

```
.sticky{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a simplified snippet out of your code and it's working nicely.
Your problem should be with another styling!

See it working:

```css
.media {
  float: left;
  height: 2000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, green 50%, blue 100%);
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
  <img class="sticky" src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100">
</div>
```

Comment: Strange, it's only in one other div which doesn't have a styling. Thanks for your help though.